# CSS does not load

Tags: asp.net, .net, html, css

everyone. We're in a bit of hurry here. We're facing a problem. In one of our applications, CSS circumstantially crashes. Through the IE developer tools, this is what we get:

```
UNKNOWN
   font-style: normal
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
   [...]
.section_head
   font-style: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
   color: #003366
   [...]
```

This is just not right. What does UNKNOWN even mean? Has it failed to load? It's working fine in DEV, but not in Staging (both DEV and STG environments have the same .css file, but are indeed archived in different servers).

Thank you very much.
Martín.

EDIT: this is the header section:

```
<head id="ctl00_Head1"><title>
Local Market Development – Activity Tracking Tool
</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="./App_Themes/SMT.SE/Css/SMT.SE.css?v=12" />

<link href="/WebResource.axd?d=-NDJxaf2kREMPzEZaAiVcFh35WR6hCcIbA_i4l7VEJZ0i508zIYCADtpX3503O
-khhzaW0BxzunxkTE-JqRu89g8VZ54u9zL-Y_VOk9q3PaiXxUtWIDyGgXN8doQb6-
4DFG9V2sS1UTOwjHauX2xcZ4uTu01&amp;t=634877831646886861" 
type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /></head>
```

Comment: If you remove those two declarations does the error go away?

Comment: Could you show the original css code (of the failing part)

Comment: Not enough info. Show us the head section of the page this occurs on.

Comment: is the file loading correctly/

Comment: @mcassano: no, it does not go away.

Comment: @dmaij: It should be noted that I have the VERY same file in DEV, and it does not fail there.

Comment: @Shmiddty: you are right: I have edited my post.

Comment: @lbu: it certainly seems not : )

Comment: your .section_head has a typo, you are assigning family to a font-style.

Comment: Why is the stylesheet included as a webresource?

Comment: Do you have an URL for checking ourself?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a hidden char which is not UTF8 (or ANSI if your files are)? This happens from time to time when some text was copied from a Microsoft Program like Word.

Comment: Mmmmhh... but it does not seem the case. Again, it should be noted that I have the same .css in DEV environment, and it there it works perfectly.

Comment: Do you use compression, minify or something else in your STG enviroment? Some special .htaccess configuration which does not apply to DEV enviroment?